# Vserver: Recommended RAM?

Tags: virtualization, linux-vserver

I'm at the moment using shared web hosting and a Subversion server, and I'd like to have a git server as well. Now the time has come that a virtual server is less expensive than buying all other packets separately.

The vserver is mainly for private use, the web page is my private one (low bandwidth). What would you suggest me to order regarding RAM – is 512 MB okay or should I rather go for 1 GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It obviously depends on your needs, but for comparison, I have several web-sites, git-repos, postgresql and exim on a Xen-instanse with 384MB of RAM. No problem whatsoever. So 512MB should be quite sufficient (and probably quite a lot cheaper than 1GB)